# Как дождаться результата после сигнала/слота?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

Помогите пожалуйста, не разбираюсь в потоках, но очень хочу понять что и как сделать
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_and_LaTeX_via_KLFBackend подсоединил библиотеку. Сделал так чтобы после нажатия кнопки появлялось новое окно, происходило считывание с файла и показывалось pixmap, но оно отрисовывает после page.exe().

Как сделать чтобы соединение работало как функция, в смысле, как поставить таймер или как задержать?

Поток только 1, но вот mPreviewBuilderThread это библиотека, которая наследуется от QThread и я не могу понять как обращаться и пользоваться

```
slot
void MainWindow::toPage(){
    page = new QDialog;
    mPreviewBuilderThread = new KLFPreviewBuilderThread(this, input, settings);
    /* код из примера */
    connect(mPreviewBuilderThread, SIGNAL(previewAvailable(const QImage&, bool)),
            this, SLOT(show_task(const QImage&, bool)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    page.exe();
}
```

Comment: Возможно нужно использовать ассинхронное программирование, но я не знаю как. По идее это его части

Comment: @Настасья каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вот так надо сделать:

```cpp
void MainWindow::toPage(){
    mPreviewBuilderThread = new KLFPreviewBuilderThread(this, input, settings);

    connect(mPreviewBuilderThread, SIGNAL(previewAvailable(const QImage&, bool)),
            this, SLOT(show_task(const QImage&, bool)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    // Запускаем поток
    mPreviewBuilderThread->start();

    QDialog page;
    page.exec(); 

    // Не забыть, что где-то надо поток остановить и удалить   
}
```

Comment: только один поток, и слот show_task вызывается после отображения page.exec();

Comment: @kaliarty то есть, уже после того, как будет закрыто окно диалога?

Comment: верно, можете посоветовать как открыть второй поток?

Comment: @kaliarty так же как и первый. А в чем тогда вопрос и затруднения?

Comment: первый потом открыт по умолчанию. Я не понимаю почему connect вызывается не сразу и как сделать так чтобы он сразу работал?

Comment: @kaliarty видимо потому что для создания preview нужно какое-то время. У вас не очень понятно сформулирован вопрос - что значит "но оно отрисовывается на глазах", например?

Comment: отрисовывает после page.exec(), если идти по отладке, то заходит в слот show_task после page.exec().